# Is set difference left-associative?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I encountered the following exercise:
$A\setminus B\setminus C$, where $A,B$ and $C$ are all sets.
This made me wonder: if there are multiple set differences in a row, the order of calculation goes from left to right? i.e. is set difference calculations left-associative?
Should I calculate it $(A\setminus B)\setminus C$?
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Set differences are not associative. Draw a venn diagram to see why. So the notation $A\setminus B\setminus C$ is ambiguous.

Comment: Convert set difference to intersection with a complement the same way you convert subtraction to addition of a negative.

Answer (score 1):

You must specify how you bracket the expression. Here is a simple example showing that in general $(A\backslash B) \backslash C \neq A \backslash (B \backslash C)$: take $A = \{1,2,3\}$, $B = \{2,3\}$ and $C = \{3\}$. Then $(A\backslash B) \backslash C = \{1\}$ but $ A \backslash (B \backslash C) = \{1,3\}$

Comment: Excellent point! How would you answer this book exercise, though? I don't know if the book wanted to teach us an intrinsic principle of set difference or they missed a bracket, making the exercise so ambiguous that becomes unsalable. Thank you

Comment: @Sisyphus: Unless the author has explicitly stated a convention (e.g., associate to the left), the expression is simply ambiguous, and the exercise is flawed.